# android service using SystemClock.elapsedRealTime() instead of SystemClock.uptimeMillis() works in emulator but not in samsung captivate?

Tags: android, android-emulator

First question here in stackoverflow :)

I'm running a little android 2.2 app to log cpu frequency usage. It is set up as a service that will write the data every 10 seconds using a new thread. The code for that part is very basic (see below).

It works fine, except that it would not keep track of time while the phone is asleep (which, I know, is the expected behavior). Thus, I changed the code to use SystemClock.elapsedRealTime() instead. Problem is, in emulator both commands are equivalent, but in the phone the app will start the thread but it will never execute the mHandler.postAtTime command. Any advice regarding why this is happening or how to overcome the issue is greatly appreciated.

PS: stopLog() is not being called. That's not the problem.

```
    mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            long millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - mStartTime;
            int seconds = (int) (millis / 1000);
            int minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds     = seconds % 60;

            String freq = readCPU ();
            if (freq == null)
                Toast.makeText(CPU_log_Service.this, "CPU frequency is unreadable.\nPlease make sure the file has read rights.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String str = new String ((minutes*60 + seconds) + ", " + freq + "\n");
            if (!writeLog (str)) stopLog();
            mHandler.postAtTime(this, mStartTime + (((minutes * 60) + seconds + 10) * 1000));
    }};

    mStartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the documentation states, for `postAtTime()`, "The time-base is uptimeMillis()." Hence, you cannot just decide to use `elapsedRealTime()`.

I would recommend you simply use `postDelayed()`, to eliminate the whole time-base problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was looking everywhere except on the most obvious place. I preferred the postAtTime() variant because it makes easier to make sure the log doesn't drift from round numbers (purely aesthetics). I tried to come up with some options to force multiple of 10 seconds but they didn't work so far.